# Don't laugh, but what on earth am i missing?

Tags: nsstring

OK, I probably have no business trying to learn an OOP and I'm having trouble with the simplest little first program. I am getting a message that my implementation is incomplete (I commented the line that is giving 4 errors below). What is wrong? It wants a type specifier among other things, but don't I give it one with NSString? I do notice that NSString doesn't change color to a green type color in XCODE in the implementation like it does in the interface.

ALSO, why do we need to declare the method in the interface and type the exact same thing in the implementation? that is, why the need to type the startDrinking: (NSString*) newBeverage in both?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Drinks : NSObject {
    NSString *beverage;
}

- (void) startDrinking: (NSString*) newBeverage;  // setter
- (void) printDrink;

@end


@implementation Drinks
{

//THIS NEXT LINE IS WHERE I GET 4 ERRORS
    - (void) startDrinking: (NSString *) newBeverage {
        beverage = [[NSString alloc]initwithString:newBeverage]
        }


    -(void) printDrink {

                NSLog(@"How is your", beverage);
            }

        }

@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    Drinks *beverage = [[Drinks alloc] init];

    [beverage startDrinking:@"Lemonade"];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your question is too chatty.*

You missed a semi-colon in line `beverage = [[NSString alloc]initwithString:newBeverage]`

The line should be :

```
beverage = newBeverage;
```

and the NSLog line should be:

```
NSLog(@"How is your %@", beverage);
```

and for the declaration of method signature in header, it is followed by C and C++ . You can think of, the Compiler needs to know which functions are available first.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry, that was my first post. I don't see where exactly the semi-colon should go in the line. I tried putting one everywhere and still get type specifier missing and ; needed at end of declarations

Comment: I did add the semi-colon where you showed, but the same 4 errors still occur.

Comment: I'm getting:
Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers and type name requires a specific qualifier and type specifier missing defaults to int

Comment: I figured it out just now...I guess i wasn't supposed to have curly bracelet after the implementation. Got rid of it and those errors and left just one final error: NSLog(@"How is your", beverage); (now I'm getting: data argument not used by format string

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the `{` right below `@implementation Drinks`.
That's why the alignment is messed up too.

In general, if you can't find an error on the line it is reported on, just check any extraneous or missing parenthesis, brackets or braces. 
The weird alignment is another clue to this.

Hope this helps. Also, like some other said, it helps if your subject is more meaningful. Not just for yourself, but also for any others that might be having a similar problem